# Apache VHosts configuration ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, virtualhost

**The problem**

My Apache/2.2.15 doesn´t serve websites I want to acces via subdomains.
When hitting an URL, e.g. `domain.tld` or `subdomain.domain.tld` an error occurs `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

**My file structure**

In `/var/www/html` there are the folders

- `domain-production` - contains index.html with test `<h1></h1>`
- `domain-staging` - contains index.html with other test `<h1></h1>`
- `phpMyAdmin` - contains a standard installation of that tool

**What I did**

Check httpd for listening on port 80

```
tcp   0   0   :::80   :::*   LISTEN   2227/httpd
```

In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
set document root to

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

Later on set directory to

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Finally set subdomains `staging` and `phpmyadmin`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain-production
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName staging.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain-staging
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The issue was I had to restart iptables. I have to say that I run iRedMail which wrote most of the firewall rules. So port 80 was accidentally blocked because of I have no idea ... although iptables state an `ACCEPT`.